# How do I create a flexible architecture that allows me to operate on several different underlying data models?

Tags: c#, generics, architecture, repository, repository-pattern

I'm trying to create an application with a very flexible architecture. It should be able to easily swap out any one layer with a different component, as long as it adheres to the same interfaces.

More specifically, my business logic layer should not care how or where my data layer retrieves the data objects that the business logic layer requests. Or what kind of calculations the data layer might have to do to transform the data object into an object that is usable by the business layer.

In my initial attempt at solving this, the issue I'm having is that when the business logic uses generics, the data layer does not know what to do with those types. For example, let's say my business logic is operating on the Car type.

```
abstract class Car
{
    public abstract int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

While my data layer might be operating on different types, like these:

```
class VolvoCar : Car
{
    public override int Wheels { get; set; }
}

class HondaCar : Car
{
    public override int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on which repository I'm currently using, a VolvoRepository or a HondaRepository. These are injected through IoC containers so the business logic does not know which implementation lies underneath. These classes might have other, different properties too, but my business logic layer only cares about a common definition of Car, and shouldn't ever have to worry about what kind of car it is.

My problem is this: When I now want to access the data layer by use of generics, there's a disconnect between the layers on what types they operate on. For example, my business logic might ask my Repository to Get(). But if my Repository is of type VolvoRepository, what I really want it to do is instantiate a VolvoCar and return it as a Car. But I don't think my Repository has any simple way of inferring that. Of course it's possible through ugly means, like reflection or

```
if (T is Car) return new VolvoCar();
```

But I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing this, that "just works".

In short, how can I make it so that my business logic can simply operate on the common definitions of types, and let the data layer handle the specific quirks of the underlying data model? (For example, maybe Honda stores their Wheels in sets of two, so loading a HondaCar would mean multiplying the wheel property by 2 before it is passed to the business layer, etc.)

While this is mostly an architecture question, examples given in C# would be appreciated. I'm also open to radically different approaches if my thinking is way off. The only hard requirements are that I need my business logic to be able to work on top of several different data models that all contain definitions for roughly the same objects (POCOs). The data layer components must then be responsible for handling translation between these POCOs and the underlying data model.

Comment: Seems you me like you are looking for an abstract factory pattern to create your repositories.

Comment: Why would you need to check if the entity requested via Get() is a car? To me it seems you are implementing generics while your domain has no need for it. Maybe you can first define the interface of an `ICarRepository` or an `IEngineRepository` before going into implementation details

Comment: The reason I would like to use generics is that my underlying ORM allows for generics. It would be ideal to expose that all the way up to the business logic layer. I could of course make the method GetCar() instead, but then I would need one such method for every type in every repo. It's a workable solution, but not as sleek as just having everything work as soon a I define the types. The abstract factory pattern looks very close to what I want, so I'll experiment with that and see what I can do. But it doesn't seem to trivially allow for the generics I want.

Comment: Ok I see, in that case the inheritance mapping may also be supported by the ORM. I also recommend [this article about the repository pattern](http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/) which might give you a head start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, your problem seems more or less clear. As long as you prefer C# examples:

```
public abstract class TypeUnsafeObject 
{ 
    public abstract object GetObject();
    public abstract void SetObject(object obj);
}
```

Then:

```
    public abstract TypeSafeObject<T> : TypeUnsafeObject
    { 
        public abstract T GetTypeSafeObject();
        public abstract void SetTypeSafeObject(T obj);
        public override object GetObject() {
            return GetTypeSafeObject();
        }
        public override void SetObject(object obj) {
            var typeSafeObj = obj as T;
            if (typeSafeObj != null) {
                SetTypeSafeObj(typeSafeObj);
            }
            else {
            // report failure
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, there are consumers, who deal with object only (as long as it's fine for them). Please note: your type-unsafe layer could be bound to whatever different class rather than just `object`. I just try to keep things obvious for simplicity sake.

That's the easiest solution to go with.

```
TypeUnsafeRepo repo = RepoFactory.GetRepoFor<VolvoCar>();
repo.Save();
```

At the same time `RepoFactory` responds with **strongly typed objects**.

---

But to be honest, I see no reason why you need generics to manage the complexity you described. I would suggest keep thing really really simple and yet easy-to-understand.